# Installing postgres on EC2 (Amazon Linux)

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-ec2, installation

Trying to install postgreSQL, and looks liked I have messed something up. I first delete postgres using commands below.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-183-130-45 /]$ rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/data
[ec2-user@ip-10-183-130-45 /]$ sudo rm -rf /var/pgsql
```

then try initdb, which for some reason fails,

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-183-130-45 /]$ sudo service postgresql initdb
Initializing database:                                     [FAILED]
```

but when I check though, the initdb does create pgsql folder,

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-183-130-45 var]$ ls -l
total 80
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 May  9  2013 account
drwxr-xr-x  9 root     root     4096 Sep 18 09:54 cache
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 May  9  2013 db
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 May  9  2013 empty
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 Nov  8 06:34 ftp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Jan  6  2012 games
drwxr-xr-x 20 root     root     4096 Oct 14 07:34 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Jan  6  2012 local
drwxrwxr-x  5 root     lock     4096 Jan 21 04:36 lock
drwxr-xr-x  7 root     root     4096 Jan 21 09:31 log
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root       10 May  9  2013 mail -> spool/mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Jan  6  2012 nis
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Jan  6  2012 opt
**drwx------  3 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 21 13:26 pgsql**
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Jan  6  2012 preserve
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Mar 14  2013 racoon
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root     4096 Jan 21 13:23 run
drwxr-xr-x  9 root     root     4096 May  9  2013 spool
drwxrwxrwt  3 root     root     4096 Jan 20 06:00 tmp
drwxrwsr-x  7 root     www      4096 Nov 17 14:38 www
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Jan  6  2012 yp
```

so I try to start the postgresql, which fails too

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-183-130-45 var]$ sudo service postgresql start

/var/pgsql is missing. Use "service postgresql initdb" to initialize
the cluster first.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Can someone help, ID what I am doing wrong? Using postgresql-9.2-1.19.

Comment: If I well remember you have to launch "service postgresql initdb" not as root but as postgres user

Comment: Quick tip: don't use Amazon Linux for PostgreSQL. Unless something's changed, their packaging of PostgreSQL is dangerous and incompetent - they silently update you to a new major version, so a `yum update` can cause your database to fail to start. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28245/7788 . Use CentOS, Fedora, Ubuntu, anything but Amazon Linux for PostgreSQL. For current-version packages see http://yum.postgresql.org/ and http://apt.postgresql.org/

Comment: but... it's really helpful, why close it?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
sudo yum remove postgresql postgresql-server
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/psql
sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server
```

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting this messages - Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a misunderstanding. Did you say that you deleted some postgres files, and then are wondering why it doesn't work?

I recommend:

- Repairing the original install of postgres.
- Removing it gracefully. With the package manager perhaps?
- Installing your new postgres with a package manager.